# labview Exception: Stack overflow when loading project from shared folder in LAN

Tags: stack-overflow, labview

When I try to open a project from a shared folder in LAN (W10 to W10) I get the following error: "labview Exception: Stack overflow (0xC00000FD) at EIP=0x000000006257B0C8".

If I open it in the "local" computer everything is OK.

Any clue from what's hapenning here? What extra information would be useful to solve the problem? Thanks for your time.

Best regards.

Comment: What happens if you try loading the individual VIs in the project folder one by one, without opening the project itself? If that doesn't get you anywhere I think your next step is NI support.

Comment: I already desisted from it. Thank you anyway.